# Why are methods missing from this object?

Tags: .net-assembly, assemblies

Having a really strange issue I haven't seen before. I am following a tutorial on how to use Selenium and ChromeDriver to script browsing. After loading WebDriver.dll and chromedriver.exe into my working directory, I run this

```
Add-Type -Path "$($WorkingDir.FullName)\WebDriver.dll"

$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
```

When I run `GetType()` on the object, it shows

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     False    ChromeDriver     OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver
```

However, when I try to access the methods, I only get these

```
PS C:\repo\> $ChromeDriver.
ApplicationCache                ApplicationCache                ClearNetworkConditions          GetType
Capabilities                    Close                           LaunchApp
CommandExecutor                 CloseDevToolsSession            Manage
CurrentWindowHandle             Dispose                         Navigate
FileDetector                    Equals                          PerformActions
HasActiveDevToolsSession        ExecuteAsyncScript              Print
HasApplicationCache             ExecuteCdpCommand               Quit
HasLocationContext              ExecuteChromeCommand            RegisterCustomDriverCommand
HasWebStorage                   ExecuteChromeCommandWithResult  RegisterCustomDriverCommands
IsActionExecutor                ExecuteCustomDriverCommand      ResetInputState
LocationContext                 ExecuteScript                   SelectCastSink
NetworkConditions               FindElement                     SetPermission
PageSource                      FindElements                    StartTabMirroring
SessionId                       GetCastIssueMessage             StopCasting
Title                           GetCastSinks                    SwitchTo
Url                             GetDevToolsSession              ToString
WebStorage                      GetHashCode
WindowHandles                   GetScreenshot
```

I'm missing a ton of methods, like these

```
FindElement(By) 
FindElementByClassName
FindElementById
FindElementByLinkText
FindElementByName
FindElementByPartialLinkText
FindElementByTagName
FindElementByXPath
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I was having some other issues with my system and had been wanting to rebuild it anyway, so I did that, and I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the methods were deprecated and finally removed. The examples I was using were very recent, so I'm surprised by this.

https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/7OF9lMjoRgI/m/45HMvlhmCQAJ

They also had the old version of the docs posted, which still listed the missing methods